# Admob advertisement (Android) is to small

Tags: android, view, admob, android-relativelayout

I placed a admob advertisement in my Android App ([Block Crusher](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.peerkesoftware.blockcrusher&feature=search_result)) and on QVGA the advertisment is smaller then the screen. On bigger resolutions there is no problem.

[image: Admob advertisment to small]

I used the following xml to add the admob advertisement to the relative layout:

```
<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/ad"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:adSize="BANNER"
    app:adUnitId="0000000000" />
```

The width of my view is set to fill_parent and when I watch the hierarchy viewer I see that the view is the full width. Still the advertisment is shown as above.

I have this problem both in the emulator as on a QVGA phone.

Anybody else has this problem? And know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was fixed when I updated the Admob SDK to version 4.1.0.

Answer (score 1):

If you wrap it in a LinearLayout, then assign it a weight, and/or assign height=50dip you should fill the area.

Banner's base are 320x50.

Comment: I tried that, but it gives no difference. The admob-view itself is big enough, but the ad inside that admob-view is to small. Maybe I should report a bug to Admob about this.